# How to Use PHP in IPhone Applications

Tags: iphone

I need to create an iPhone application using Facebook.

The facebook FBConnect API supports FQL which is similar to SQL Queries.

I would be able to create the application easily using PHP as compared to Objective-C.

So if there is any way to create an iPhone application using PHP please reply to me.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean, actually *running* PHP in an iPhone application? That sounds impossible and like a bad idea either way.

Comment: The only way would be to call php scripts on a server and then get the response. Pretty sure there no way to run php on the iPhone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you are developing something for jailbroken devices , yes it is possible to use PHP (you have to install it first from Cydia).Also note that you should implement a SQLite database if your app/script needs database functionality (you can't run a MySQL server natively on iPhone ATM).
But, as pekka mentioned, this is a really bad idea, because you must set up first a lighttpd web server on iPhone (not really comfortable), or if you're planing to implement a CLI PHP script, you should first launch it (using some C functions like `pipe()`, `dup2()`, `fork()`, `execl()`) and then parse its output inside your -not-so-Objective-C- iPhone app.

So think it again...